# How to secure ajax call (JS to PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security

my question is simple, but I can't find any updated informations about it.

Basically, I've a phonegap application :

- HTML files
- JS files
- ..

And php files on OVH server.

When the application need to CRUD the database (mysql-ovh), it's been done with ajax call.

For example :

```
if(confirm("Delete record ?")){
    params = { 
        "action": "delete_record",
        "record_id": record_id
    }
    ajax_post(params, function(data){
        if(data.status == 'success') {
            alert(data.msg);
            $.mobile.changePage( "aRandomPage.html");
        } else {
            alert("erreur : " + data.msg);
        }
    });
}
```

*NB : ajax_post is just a personalized function doing a simple ajax post so I don't have to write all informations such as file URL and so on.*

**The problem is that ANYONE could edit the javascript file** (Either by unzipping the .apk, .xap or by console if it is a web version) **and transform the params to**

```
params = { 
    "action": "delete_record",
    "record_id": 5
}
```

**and delete the record number 5** (which is not his and he shouldn't be able to) **or whatever record he wants, and doing so, he could delete all records.**

Is there a classic way to handle this I'm not aware of ?

I came up with a solution : 
I could store the password in the [storage.setItem("")](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_localstorage_localstorage.md.html), and everytime there is an access to the database through ajax, I would pass the userid (already stored in storage) and the password.
Then I would check on PHP side if password and ID are matching (Kind of a loggin thing).

That way, I would be sure the user sending the request is the owner of the record and can delete it. (I don't see how someone could bypass that since it would require the password of the user)

Downside is to store password on client, not sure it's any better..

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require the user to login first. When they login, a session variable can be set in PHP with the user ID. Then when the `delete_record` request is made, you check whether the user ID has permission to delete that record.

Comment: Can you use/maintain php session with phonegap which doesn't allow php files ?

Comment: Your question says `PHP files on OVH server`.

Comment: PHP files are only used through ajax call from phonegap app (only html/js files)

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. You should perform an AJAX call to log the user in, and it will set a session variable.

Comment: Ok, I see, I got confused between the phonegap "session" (that I am creating with storage) and the PHP session (that I wasn't aware it could maintain a session with only ajax call). Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Everytime there is an Ajax call to the php files (from the same device), there is a new session created. How can I maintain the session ? I am supposed to send back the session id from PHP to ajax response, store it in JS, and pass it from JS to PHP ajax call everytime ? Sorry, I can't find any doc on php session through ajax

Comment: PHP sessions use a cookie that it sends to the client. AJAX should save the cookie just like a normal browser. I don't know much about PhoneGap, so I don't know if that destroys the cookie.